# laravel orderby on has through related table

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by, relation

I have three tables "activity, booking and ratting"

table fields are like that

=> activity
id
name

=> booking
id
activity_id

=> review
id
booking_id
rating

I am getting a list of activities and I want to do activities list sorting by rating.

then how can I do it?

Comment: Please post your models and relations you have created.

Comment: see laravel collections for this.

Comment: Activity table - column names =>  id, name
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Booking table - column names =>  id, activity_id    
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
review table - column names =>  id, booking_id , ratting 
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: One activity has many booking and one booking has many reviews